# How I set the a field in a input select (HTML) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, select, field

I will randomly select a number and define the selected field in a select with the sorted number. How I set the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the Attribute selected="selected" to the option element that you want to select.

**pseudo code**

```
function foo()
{
create list of option elements
generate random number
get a single option element at index of random number
set all options attribute "selected" = null
set the option element[at index of random number] attribute selected = "selected"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var randomNumber = 3; // just for example 
document.getElementById('select_field').selectedIndex = randomNumber;
```